# Number of ways pitchers can be selected for a baseball game .

Tags: probability, statistics, combinations

In my *Probability*  *&*  *Statistics* class, my professor put a question on the quiz and $95 \% $ of the class got the question wrong (putting the same answer as me). I understand why my professor said our answer was wrong, but I think the wording of question allows people to interpret the problem in different ways.

"For a baseball game, the managers plans to use one starter and two relievers. If he has $3$ starting pitchers and $6$ relievers available, in how many ways can he select pitchers for the game$?$"

Let me know what you think and then I'll tell you what my professor said and what most students put. Thank you!

Comment: The question is indeed a little vague, but I would say the answer is just ${3 \choose 1} \times {6 \choose 2}$.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what everyone in our class put! However, my professor said (3 C 1) x (6 C 1) x (5 C 1) because the same reliever cannot be used. I disagree with her reasoning because the question says "plan" to use, as if the manager is deciding before the game. That is why I said (3 C 1) (6 C 2). Now I got an 80 on the quiz because it was only 5 questions!

Comment: Note that 6C1 x 5C1 = 6P2, instead of 6C2.  Both answers account for the fact that the second pitcher can't be the same as the first;  the difference is whether the order matters (see answer below.)

Comment: I think your professor is wrong. This problem should not require any knowledge of baseball. This should be no different than if I want to wrap a package with one bow and two ribbons and I have three bows and six ribbons from which to choose.

Comment: Okay, thank you Michael. I assumed order didn't matter then, but I guess it did.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the issue is whether it's an ordered or unordered selection of the relief pitchers.  In a case such as this, it would be good to ask for a clarification, if that is possible.

Comment: I realize I should have done that once I got the grade back. I did not assume order mattered because the wording made it sound like the manager was selecting 2 pitchers before the game.

Comment: Probability is a subject where it's often difficult to state a "word problem" in a way that makes it completely unambiguous without giving away the method of solution.  This question has two reasonable interpretations, and a reasonable professor should be able to recognize that this is the case when this is brought to her attention.  Go to her office hours, or write her an email.  Make it clear that this is a matter of principle rather than digging for extra grades.  You can quote me and Michael Seifert, if you think that will help.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on whether the order of the relievers matters or not.  If having Smith as the first relief pitcher and Jones as the second is different from having Jones first and Smith second, then there are 3*6*5 = 90 ways to pick the pitchers.  If the order doesn't matter, then the answer is half this, or 45 different ways.

I don't know enough about baseball to know whether this distinction (between "first relief" and "second relief") is actually one that's made in practice.

Comment: "Plan" is ambiguous, to be fair.  But the manager could either plan to use Smith and then Jones (in which case order would matter), or plan to put either Smith or Jones in depending on what he feels is best in the moment (in which case order wouldn't matter.)  In both cases, though, both relief pitchers would be selected before the game;  it's what you "figured" but is not explicitly stated that gets you into trouble.

Comment: One reliever might be for "middle relief" and the other a "closer" who would only play the 9'th inning, if necessary.